# Submenu position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have scrolling a menu on my website http://www.whirlware.biz, it works fine at all but have a bug in submenus (company and services), submenu appears strange way when page is scrolled. I think I need fixed position for submenu, but when I try to make it I had awful results.

My code: (or you can inspect my website)

**stickymenu.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var left = document.getElementById("zt-mainmenu"); 

stop = (left.offsetTop - 60);


window.onscroll = function (e) {

  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset :   (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;


 if (scrollTop >= stop) { 
 left.className = 'fixed_m'; 
 } else {
 left.className = ''; 
 }

}
});
```

I tried to add this css but there was no result that I expected:

```
div.submenu-wrap {
position:fixed !important;
top:0px !important;
left:0px !important;
}
```

I can`t provide whole css code because style file is big, but if you expect site I think you can find right answer.
Can somebody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Some script are setting the position for the submenu wich is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a top property that the js plugin is inserting. Either edit the plugin to remove the top property inline, or use this bit of CSS on an existing selector you have:

```
div.menusys_mega .menusub_mega {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: inherit !important;
}
```

It's not ideal because of the !important, but at least you will see what happens when you cancel out the top property.